# JDBC: Find out if query was successful?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm using JDBC with mysql. I can get my queries to work great.
But for update queries for instance I was wondering if there was any way to determine whether the update was successful for for example if the row could not be found.

```
UPDATE TABLE SET  column =  'newvalue' WHERE  primary_key =2
```

I would like to get the specific error message if possible, this way I can throw a specific exception as to why the query failed.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

executeUpdate() will return the number of rows that were affected by your SQL statement:

```
int rows = stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE ...");
System.out.println(rows + " rows updated");
```

Of course you could have found out yourself by simply [looking at the JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29):

> *Returns: either (1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing*

Comment: The thing is I want the specific reason the update failed so I can throw an exception with that reason.

Comment: @user1795609: it will only "fail" if you violate a constraint or if you have a syntax error - then a SQLException will be thrown. If 0 is returned it simply means non rows in the table matched your `where` criteria - that's not considered "failing". That's an acceptable outcome of an `UPDATE` statement.

Answer (score 3):

[executeUpdate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29) returns the row count of rows affected. You could use this to check that your update was executed successfully:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE TABLE ...");
int rowsUpdated = pstmt.executeUpdate(); 
if (rowsUpdated == 0) {
   // handle no update
}
```

Comment: That is nice but I actually wanted a way of getting the specific error message for instance if the row is not found, it would return me some sort of error message I could use to throw an exception.

Comment: @user1795609: if the row was not found, `rowsUpdated` will be `0`.